# thingsboard - Telemetry is being split into 2 mssessages

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I am trying to send the following data via tb-gateway mqtt connector

`'{"timestamp": 1670415775, "camera": "testcamera", "alert": "Temperature", "guid": "241ffb1c-5d8f-4959-a34a-02edf32487a1", "highTemp": "false", "temperature": "95.9\u00baF/ 35.5\u00baC", "bottomRightX": 3648, "mask": false, "imgPath": "somedummyurl", "timeSent": 1670415777}'`

but it is being split into 2 messages

part1:

`{"timestamp": 1670415775, "camera": "testcamera", "alert": "Temperature", "guid": "241ffb1c-5d8f-4959-a34a-02edf32487a1", "highTemp": "false", "temperature": "95.9\u00baF/ 35.5\u00baC", "bottomRightX": 3648}`

part2:

`{"mask": false, "imgPath": "somedummyurl", "timeSent": 1670415777}`

I tried setting `maxPayloadSizeBytes: 1024` in `tb-gateway.yaml`, but it splits the message into individual key-value pairs

I have created a rule chain that works only on the full payload.

**How to stop this splitting?**

**How to aggregate this split telemetry and then invoke my further rule chain?**

**I am using tb-gateway 3.2.1, tb-ce-3.2.1**

Comment: This is fixed in v3.2 version, tb-gateway 3.2.1 doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I put the value of maxPayloadSizeBytes 1024000 and it was correct
According to the gateway code, if the telemetry value is less than the maxPayloadSizeBytes, it will reduce the telemetry until it reaches the specified limit.
According to the code in addition to the information you send, other information is added to the telemetry